# Window redraw breaks after a few seconds

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a main HWND with several child HWNDs. When I start the code the windows all draw properly and show up as they should, I can even move the main window around which essentially invokes `InvalidateRect()` calls which call a redraw of the main and child windows. However, after about two seconds, all of this functionality stops and upon moving the window the **main window draw ends up drawing all of the child windows at the size of the main window**. Note that this problem occurs with any redrawing of the main window. This is quite strange, and I am inclined to think that the problem lies with my HWND setup and not the OpenGL integration as both my GL child window and the other HWND child windows are subject to the issue.

Here is my main window creation:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {

    

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(7, 7, 8));
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    

    //MessageBox(NULL, _T("This message box is completely unnecessary and is designed to annoy you."), _T("Annoyance"), NULL);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1600, 900, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindowEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }


    
    


    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Here is the main window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(_In_ HWND   hWnd, _In_ UINT   message, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam) {

    

    //a = std::make_tuple<float, float, float>(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);




    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Data Grapher for Paper");

    RECT rcClient;

    WNDCLASSEXW wcex1;
    wcex1.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex1.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wcex1.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)GLProc;
    wcex1.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex1.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex1.hInstance = glInstance;
    wcex1.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex1.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex1.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex1.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    wcex1.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wcex1.lpszClassName = _T("GLClass");
    wcex1.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex1.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&wcex1);

    WNDCLASSEXW dataViewClass;
    dataViewClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    dataViewClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    dataViewClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)DataProc;
    dataViewClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    dataViewClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    dataViewClass.hInstance = hInst;
    dataViewClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(dataViewClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    dataViewClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    dataViewClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(27, 27, 28));
    dataViewClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    dataViewClass.lpszClassName = _T("DataClass");
    dataViewClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(dataViewClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&dataViewClass);

    WNDCLASSEXW dataTextClass;
    dataTextClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    dataTextClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    dataTextClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)dataTextProc;
    dataTextClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    dataTextClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    dataTextClass.hInstance = hInst;
    dataTextClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(dataTextClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    dataTextClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    dataTextClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(27, 27, 28));
    dataTextClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    dataTextClass.lpszClassName = _T("dataTextClass");
    dataTextClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(dataTextClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&dataTextClass);
    
    
    WNDCLASSEXW quitButtonClass;
    quitButtonClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    quitButtonClass.style = BS_OWNERDRAW;//CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    quitButtonClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)quitButtonProc;
    quitButtonClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    quitButtonClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    quitButtonClass.hInstance = hInst;
    quitButtonClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(quitButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    quitButtonClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    quitButtonClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(27, 27, 28));
    quitButtonClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    quitButtonClass.lpszClassName = _T("quitButtonClass");
    quitButtonClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(quitButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&quitButtonClass);

    WNDCLASSEXW saveImageButtonClass;
    saveImageButtonClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    saveImageButtonClass.style = BS_OWNERDRAW;//CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    saveImageButtonClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)saveImageButtonProc;
    saveImageButtonClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    saveImageButtonClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    saveImageButtonClass.hInstance = hInst;
    saveImageButtonClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(saveImageButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    saveImageButtonClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    saveImageButtonClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(27, 27, 28));
    saveImageButtonClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    saveImageButtonClass.lpszClassName = _T("saveImageButtonClass");
    saveImageButtonClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(saveImageButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&saveImageButtonClass);


    WNDCLASSEXW switchModeButtonClass;
    switchModeButtonClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    switchModeButtonClass.style = BS_OWNERDRAW;//CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    switchModeButtonClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)switchModeButtonProc;
    switchModeButtonClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    switchModeButtonClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    switchModeButtonClass.hInstance = hInst;
    switchModeButtonClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(switchModeButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    switchModeButtonClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    switchModeButtonClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(27, 27, 28));
    switchModeButtonClass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    switchModeButtonClass.lpszClassName = _T("switchModeButtonClass");
    switchModeButtonClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(switchModeButtonClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassExW(&switchModeButtonClass);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        
        /*
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        
        // Here your application is laid out.
        // For this introduction, we just print out "Hello, Windows desktop!"
        // in the top left corner.


        //doGL(hdc);


        TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, greeting, _tcslen(greeting));
        // End application-specific layout section.

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        */
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        
        
        InitCommonControls();
        
        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("quitButtonClass"), _T("Quit"), WS_CHILD, 20, 50, 100, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)1, hInst, NULL);

        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("saveImageButtonClass"), _T("Save Image"), WS_CHILD, 140, 50, 80, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)2, hInst, NULL);

        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("switchModeButtonClass"), _T("Toggle Clock"), WS_CHILD, 20, 90, 100, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)3, hInst, NULL);

        

        w = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("GLClass"), _T("GL"), WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 160, 90, hWnd, (HMENU)4, hInst, NULL);
        
        


        HDC dc = GetDC(w);
        HGLRC rc = wglCreateContext(dc);


        wglMakeCurrent(dc, rc);

        

        //glfwInit();
        int argc = 1;
        char* argv[1] = { (char*)"Something" };

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glewInit();

        initializeText();
        
        imageSaveQueued = false;

        graphScale = .8f;


        HWND da = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("DataClass"), _T("Data"), WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 160, 90, hWnd, (HMENU)5, hInst, NULL);
        //makes it so the data field accepts files
        DragAcceptFiles(da, TRUE);
        
        //set the data mode to by bz graph by default
        mode = 1;


        
        

        //dataList = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, TEXT("Load Data"), WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS, 300, 700, 500, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)6, hInst, NULL);

        //dataText = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("dataTextClass"), _T("dataText"), WS_CHILD, 200, 200, 200, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)7, hInst, NULL);

        //createListColumn(dataList, 1, L"Year", 0);
        //createListItem(dataList, _T("Thing"), 0);

        //SendMessage(dataList, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)"words");
        

        //CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Save Graph"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 140, 90, 100, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)7, NULL, NULL);


        //trackA = CreateWindowEx(0, TRACKBAR_CLASS, _T("Start"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_ENABLESELRANGE, 900, 700, 200, 30, hWnd, (HMENU)8, hInst, NULL);
        //trackB = CreateWindowEx(0, TRACKBAR_CLASS, _T("End"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_ENABLESELRANGE, 900, 730, 200, 30, hWnd, (HMENU)8, hInst, NULL);

        //SendMessage(trackA, TBM_SETRANGE,
            //(WPARAM)TRUE,                   // redraw flag 
            //(LPARAM)MAKELONG(0, 100));

        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&rcClient);
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        
        /*
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        */

        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 7) {
            smoothLine = !smoothLine;
            InvalidateRect(w, NULL, TRUE);
        }

        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        FreeLibrary(comctllib);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm reluctant to paste more code here in the initial question as there is quite a lot more code, but if there is something more needed (including screenshots) I am happy to add it.

Comment: Your window procedure is called many many times. Each time it is called for any message, you register many  window classes. Why keep trying to tgeuster them? Do you understand when a window proc is called? You should throw away all the code and get a better tutorial. The actual issue is you leaking GDI objects, e.g. brushes. There are many other problems with this code.

Comment: "The actual issue is you leaking GDI objects..." where do you see this? Yes I understand when the procedures are called, I just left those class registrations there from the initial tutorial I used to start building the program.

Comment: Every call to CreateSolidBrush is a GDI leak. You have a call to GetDC that isn't released - GDI leak. This happens every single time your window processes a message.

Comment: Ah yes haha. This comment gave me a laugh. You were correct, moving the class registrations to an external function called only once fixed the issue.

Comment: [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) is the absolute minimum you'll need to work through. Though, really, you will want to get a [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).